# Assembly: How to return a pointer?

Tags: loops, pointers, assembly, x86-64

The function inventory take an array of device pointers and call evaluate to find out what the variation is. The inventory function then returns a pointer that has the highest variation.

```
unsigned short evaluate(Struct Device *thing);

struct Device *inventory(struct Device *things[], int count);
```

device.h:

```
struct Device{
   char name[20];
   short adjustments[8];
   short avg;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "device.h"

/* from device.h, shown here to make it easier to code
struct Device
{   
    char name[20];
    short adjustments[8];
    short avg;
};
*/

struct Device things[] =
{
    { "Museum Quality",{ 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1}, 1 },
    { "Fell off truck",
        { 0x7fff, 0x7fff, 0x7fff, 0x7fff, 0x7fff, 0x7fff, 0x7fff, 0x7fff},
    2 },

    /* the casts are there since C constants are ints and you can't make
     * them shorts and negative numbers look like overflow */
    { "Fell down stairs",
    { 0x7ff0, (unsigned short)0x800f, 0x7ffe, (unsigned short)0x8001, 
    0x7ffd, (unsigned short)0x8002, 0x7fff, 0x7f00}, 
    3 },

    { "On left side",{ 10, 11, 10, 12, 10, 13, 10, 14}, 4 },
    { "On right side",{ -300, -321, -320, -332, -320, -313, -310, -314}, 5 }
};


/*
struct Device *inventory(struct Device *things[], int count);
*/

int main()
{

    struct Device *pointers[1 + sizeof(things) / sizeof(things[0])] 
        = {NULL};
    const int count =  sizeof(things) / sizeof(things[0]);

    struct Device *worst = NULL;

    int i;


    for (i=0; i< count; i++)
    {
        printf("Loading %s into pointers\n", things[i].name);
        pointers[i] = &things[i];
    }
    pointers[i] = NULL;

    worst = inventory(pointers, count);

    printf("main: The worst is %s\n", worst->name);


    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

calibrate.s: # calculates the average and returns the variability

```
    movq %r11, %rax
    sarq $3, %rax
    movl %eax, 36(%rdi)
    subq %rcx, %rdx
    movq %rdx, %rax
```

evaluate.s: # calls calibrate and returns the variability

```
        call calibrate
```

inventory.s:

rdi is the parameter that holds an array of device pointers, #rbx is a copy of rdi, so it stores array of pointers of devices, #r12 stores count of valid pointers, #r14 stores max variation, #r15 stores the device pointer with the most variation.

```
        movq %rdi, %r15         #r15 stores pointer with most variable

   loop: 
        movq (%rbx,%r12,8), %rdi
        call evaluate
        
        cmpq %r14, %rax
        jle skipmax
        movq %rax, %r14
        movq (%rbx, %r12,8), %r15
 skipmax:
        decq %r12
        cmpq $0, %r12
        jge loop

        movq %r13, %rsi
        movq $.LC0, %rdi
        movq $0, %rax
        call printf
            
        movq %r15, %rdx
        movq %r14, %rsi
        movq $.LC1, %rdi
        movq $0, %rax
        call printf

        movq %r15, %rax
```

I run the program, result is: r14 is getting the highest variation correctly, but LC0 prints correct highest variability (r14) but empty name (r15), and the C program that is trying to print the name stored in rax is also empty, the print statement prints:

*The maximum variation is 65534 from*

instead, it should print:

*The maximum variation is 65534 from Fell down stairs*

The name is not being printed as you can see from above.

after Further trouble shooting, I found out that r15 has the correct pointer, and its adjustment and avg values are correct, it is just name is empty string, any idea why? maybe since the name is a char array, and it is not being copied correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried single step in the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure `evaluate` obeys the ABI and doesn't destroy R15, and that it returns a 64-bit integer correctly sign-extended into RAX, not `int` or `short` or something?  Are you sure you want the device pointer, not the pointer-to-device-pointer (i.e. pointer to the array entry)?  If the latter, `lea` instead of `mov`.  If you do want the former, then I don't think the bug is in this code.

Comment: Yes, evaluate itself is working fine, I tested it. It is not touching r15 at all. Strangely even without calling evaluate, if I simply copy the first pointer in rdi (it holds an array of pointers), it is still not working!

Comment: Signature of inventory function (this function): struct Device *inventory(struct Device *things[], int count);

Comment: Signature of evaluate: unsigned short evaluate(struct Device *thing);

Comment: What do you mean, r15 is "empty"? A register can't be empty, it always contains some value.  Do you mean it's a null pointer (0)?

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve], with complete buildable code for this function as well as for `evaluate` (at least a stub), and a `main` function which calls them with appropriate input.  I agree with Peter that I don't see any bugs in what's here, therefore the bug must be in code you haven't shown us.  The lack of such an example is why this question already has 2 close votes, and one more would close it.

Comment: let edit my question now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the input, I think now you have more information on my question.

Comment: Sorry, it's not an MRE unless I can paste it into a file and have it compile, run, and reproduce the bug.  We want to be able to investigate this by testing the program, not just by staring at the code.

Comment: In particular, what's this function `print`?  It looks suspiciously like `printf`...

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, it is a printf

Comment: Then fix your question to make it a [mcve], instead of just leaving comments.  Did you miss Nate's point about having the question be something that could truly be copy/pasted and built into a program someone could debug on their own machine if they wanted to?

Comment: Also, what exactly value is in R15, when you check with a debugger (like GDB)?  Is it `0` (NULL pointer), or a pointer to an empty string, or what?

Comment: @NateEldredge all my codes are attached. r15 is partially right, it is has the most variability, but the name is empty, that is what my problem is. somehow, I am not copying over the name correctly since it is a char array? char name[20]

Comment: @PeterCordes 15 is partially right, it is has the most variability, but the name is empty, that is what my problem is. somehow, I am not copying over the name correctly since it is a char array? char name[20]

Comment: Thanks for the code.  It was now very easy to find out with a debugger that by the time of the `printf` in `inventory`, all but the first entry of your `things` array have had the first two bytes of the `name` member overwritten with zeros, so they print as empty string.  Now I think it will be very easy to set a watchpoint to see how that is happening.

Comment: And immediately the culprit is identified: `movl %eax, 36(%rdi)` in `calibrate`.  It's supposed to write to `rdi->avg`, but it's a 32-bit move and `avg` is 16 bits, so the next 2 bytes get overwritten.  Make it `movw %ax, 36(%rdi)`.  So guess what: the bug was not where you thought, staring at the code you originally posted was futile, and running a debugger on the complete code was quite effective.

Comment: yes, that fixed the problem! the problem with me is that when I use GDB debugger, I can not see the value of r15, there is no scroll bar to allow me to see it, the top few registers i can see are; rbx, rax, rdi rsi, but r15 is not showing. can you show me what is a good debugging tool for assembly?

Comment: I have to remove my code now in case my classmates copy it, and that is not allowed. Thank you so much! @NateEldredge

Comment: If you have your terminal set up correctly, gdb commands like `info registers` will pause after each screenful so you can read them.  A decent terminal will also let you scroll back with a hotkey or mouse wheel.  Alternatively, if you just want to see one register instead of the full dump, try `p $r15`.  You can get other formats with `p/x $r15`, or dump memory at that address with `x/whatever $r15`.

Comment: @EmperorHan: Er, StackOverflow would really rather you didn't remove it, since it will make the post useless to others.  Ideally you would have cut the code down to something that was safe to share.  Can you at least leave enough so that the bug and its cause can be seen?

Comment: @NateEldredge sure, let me try

Comment: I rolled back the vandalism to the question that invalidates the answer before I looked at comments.  It's still going to be there in the edit history for anyone that cares to look, although it might not come up on google.  As Nate said, perhaps you can turn the question into a [mcve] of the problem, or a question about how to debug this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The bug

The bug is `movl %eax, 36(%rdi)` at line 38 of `calibrate.s`.  This is apparently supposed to write to the `avg` member of the relevant `Device`, but it's a 32-bit store and `Device::avg` is a  16-bit `short`.  So it should be `movw %ax, 36(%rdi)`.

### How I found it with gdb

Hopefully this will provide some information about what gdb can do and how to use it effectively.

I set a breakpoint at the second `printf` in `inventory`, at which point I did `x/s $rdx` to see what string `%rdx` points to:

```
(gdb) x/s $rdx
0x4040ac <things+76>:   ""
```

Okay, so it is an empty string, but it's at offset `76` within `things`, which you could check is the address of `things[2].name`.  That's not supposed to be an empty string, so let's see what has happened to `things`.

```
(gdb) p things
$4 = {{name = "Museum Quality\000\000\000\000\000", adjustments = {0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1}, 
    avg = 0}, {name = "\000\000ll off truck\000\000\000\000\000", adjustments = {32767, 32767, 32767, 
      32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767}, avg = 32767}, {name = "\000\000ll down stairs\000\000\000", 
    adjustments = {32752, -32753, 32766, -32767, 32765, -32766, 32767, 32512}, avg = 8159}, {
    name = "\000\000 left side\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", adjustments = {10, 11, 10, 12, 10, 13, 
      10, 14}, avg = 11}, {name = "\000\000 right side\000\000\000\000\000\000", adjustments = {-300, 
      -321, -320, -332, -320, -313, -310, -314}, avg = -317}}
```

Hmm, the first two bytes of `things[2].name` are now null, and for that matter several of the other too.  That's not how they were initialized, and the names are not supposed to be modified at all, so how did that happen?  A watchpoint will show us which instruction is to blame.

```
(gdb) watch things[1].name[0]
Hardware watchpoint 3: things[1].name[0]
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
...
Hardware watchpoint 3: things[1].name[0]

Old value = 70 'F'
New value = 0 '\000'
calibrate () at calibrate.s:39
39          subq %rcx, %rdx
```

Note that this is the instruction *after* the one that triggered the watchpoint.  So we back up to line 38, think for a moment, and there we are.

Comment: This is excellent! Stack overflow constantly is easily my favorite place to go for asking a computer science related question!